# Freeing memory in a function

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm writing a simple program in C that finds anagrams of words based on looking them up in a hash table. What I have is an array of hash tables, where words are indexed by their length and hashed within by the summation of their letters, e.g. a = 1, b = 2, etc.

I'm still getting acquainted with dynamic memory management in C, so this question may be quite simple, but I have a functions that allocate and deallocate memory for each hash table (and its inside data).

I originally wrote this program using a single hash table and after running the program through valgrind I found that the memory had been freed correctly and there were no leaks. However, when expanding the program to use an array of hash tables, valgrind began to find possible leaks (though it's reporting them as still reachable). I'm confused as to why the memory isn't being freed correctly in the array of hash tables, although each hash table in the array is being run through the deallocate function that was used originally.

Gist with the full code [Full Code](https://gist.github.com/4559692)

```
typedef struct Bucket Bucket;
typedef struct HashTable HashTable;

struct Bucket {
  char* data;
  Bucket *next;
};

struct HashTable {
  int size;
  Bucket **buckets;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

  // Allocate memory for array of hash tables
  HashTable** hash_array = (HashTable**) malloc(sizeof(HashTable*) * WORD_SIZE);
  for(i = 0; i < WORD_SIZE; i++) {
    hash_alloc(&hash_array[i], BUCKET_COUNT);
  }

  // Main logic here...

  // Free memory
  for(i = 0; i < WORD_SIZE; i++) {
    hash_dealloc(hash_array[i]);
  }
  free(hash_array);
  return 0;
}
```

Hash Table Allocation function

```
void hash_alloc(HashTable** a, unsigned int size) {
  *a = (HashTable*) malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
  (*a)->buckets = (Bucket**) malloc(sizeof(Bucket*) * size);
  (*a)->size = size;
}
```

Hash Table Deallocation function

```
void hash_dealloc(HashTable* a) {
  int i;
  Bucket* current, *temp;
  for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
    current = a->buckets[i];
    while(current != NULL) {
      temp = current;
      free(temp->data);
      current = current->next;
      free(temp);
    }
    free(current);
  }
  free(a->buckets);
  free(a);
}
```

Add to hash table function

```
void add_to_hash_array(HashTable** a, char* data) {
    // Removed some other logic for readability...

    replace_str(data, "\n", "\0");
    newNode->data = strdup(data);
    newNode->next = currentTable->buckets[index];
    currentTable->buckets[index] = newNode;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Valgrind output

```
==39817== 261,120 bytes in 128 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 7
==39817==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39817==    by 0x400A38: hash_alloc (main.c:73)
==39817==    by 0x4008B0: main (main.c:39)
==39817== 
==39817== 286,936 bytes in 31,553 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 7
==39817==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39817==    by 0x4EBAD71: strdup (strdup.c:43)
==39817==    by 0x400D4D: add_to_hash_array (main.c:141)
==39817==    by 0x400914: main (main.c:51)
==39817== 
==39817== 504,848 bytes in 31,553 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 7
==39817==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==39817==    by 0x400D16: add_to_hash_array (main.c:136)
==39817==    by 0x400914: main (main.c:51)
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code without the superfluous casts etc. so as to make it more readable?

Comment: I've edited some of the irrelevant logic out and left the allocs and deallocs that are important for the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can we see `HashTable` and `Bucket` declarations?

Comment: Sure. I've just edited them in.

Comment: `HashTable** hash_array = (HashTable**) malloc(sizeof(HashTable*) * WORD_SIZE);` Why don't use the Hash_alloc() function instead ?

Comment: @ChristianBenincasa : Please post the whole code.

Comment: `free(arg_dup);` & `free(dict_word);`: you've deleted a bit too much or should delete these two statements too. The code doesn't compile as it is right now. `add_to_hash_array` is unused, remove it.

Comment: I think you should memset the array of buckets pointers to 0 in your hash_alloc function, otherwise checking `current != NULL` in hash_dealloc is just luck?

Comment: @stefan add_to_hash_array is unused because I removed the logic to make the code more readable.

Comment: @TOC Here's a gist of the full code https://gist.github.com/4559692

Comment: @stefan check out the gist I just posted. Compiles with gcc last I checked.

Comment: @ChristianBenincasa I don't care if it compiles in _another version_ somewhere else. The question _here_ is bad in the ways I've told you. Fix it, if you want to improve the chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: @stefan I took them out.

Comment: I've copied your code from github and it's giving me "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)" in valgrind. That's an issue you have to fix _before_ trying to find the memory leak. Additionally: Your code is useless without the file `/usr/share/dict/words` and the list of command line arguments

Comment: @ChristianBenincasa: Thanks for posting code, what the function replace_str is supposed to do? On my machine ther's no memory leaks just some conditional jumping that you can fix

Comment: @ChristianBenincasa : I use valgrind --leak-check=full

Comment: It's a good idea to initialise your pointers to NULL.  There's one place in your sample code where you declare but don't initialised a pointer "current_word" and subsequently free it when it does not seem guaranteed that it has been initialised in between.

Comment: Also, in the replace_str function you have strncpy(str, str, p-str).  That can't be what you mean.  You are copying from str back to str!

Comment: @stefan Sorry at the difficulty in reproducing the effect. I didn't mean to cast off those with Windows machines and the only reason that the code is formatted this way is because it is homework. If it's easier, I could write a more agnostic version in order to help reproduce results. How do I got about fixing the jump error? I apologize for the simple question.

Comment: @kallikak You're right about the replace_str function; I had previously refactored it an neglected to take that code out. Should I initialize all of the pointers I declare to NULL before mallocing them?

Comment: @TOC The replace_str replaces the first occurrence of a char with another char. I know it seems of not much use, but I needed to replace a bunch of newline chars.

In addition, it's strange that with --leak-check=full there are no memory leaks. I ran with --show-reachable=yes and received what I posted, which is confusing me even more.

Comment: no need to initialise to NULL before malloc, but any variable pointers that you later free should be set to NULL and only free if not NULL.  Also initialise pointer values in your structs to NULL (easier to use calloc and get this automatically) so your guards work properly.  I've had a bit more of  look over your code and your hashing worries me - you need to make sure your hash function only returns values in the range 0 to BUCKET_COUNT-1.  I made a few quick changes of this kind, and fixed your replace_str method and it no longer complains with valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `generate_anagrams`

```
void generate_anagrams(HashTable* a, char* word) {
    int index = hash(word);
    char* word_dup = strdup(word);
    char* current_word;
    string_sort(word_dup);
    printf("%s: %i size: %zi\n", word, index, strlen(word));
    Bucket* current = a->buckets[index];
    while(current != NULL) {
        if(current->data) {
            current_word = strdup(current->data);
            string_sort(current_word);
            if(strcmp(word_dup, current_word) == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", current->data);
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    free(current_word);
    free(word_dup);
}
```

you are leaking the`strdup`ed `current_word`s. Move the `free(current_word);` into the `if (current->data)`.

In `add_to_hash_array`

```
void add_to_hash_array(HashTable** a, char* data) {
    int index = hash(data);
    HashTable* currentTable = a[strlen(data)];
    Bucket* existingNode = hash_lookup(currentTable, data);
    if(existingNode == NULL) {
        Bucket *newNode = (Bucket*) malloc(sizeof(Bucket));
        if(newNode == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        replace_str(data, "\n", "\0");
        newNode->data = strdup(data);
        newNode->next = currentTable->buckets[index];
        currentTable->buckets[index] = newNode;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

You only remove the newline from `data` after you have looked it up, but you insert `data` after removing the newline, so you will not detect duplicates.

In `main`, you should not

```
 generate_anagrams(hash_array[strlen(arg_dup) + 1], arg_dup);
```

but use `hash_array[strlen(arg_dup)]` if you remove the newline right at the beginning of `add_to_hash_array`.

And of course, you should ensure that `hash` generates no out-of-range indices.

And `strncpy(str, str, p-str);` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to an answer because this nearly works.

No need to initialise to NULL before malloc, but any variable pointers that you later free should be set to NULL and only free if not NULL. Also initialise pointer values in your structs to NULL (easier to use calloc and get this automatically) so your guards work properly. I've had a bit more of look over your code and your hashing worries me - you need to make sure your hash function only returns values in the range 0 to BUCKET_COUNT-1. I made a few quick changes of this kind, and fixed your replace_str method and it no longer complains with valgrind.

Now when I run the code I see it finding the correct words to compare with, but the sorting function is not returning a sorted string, so it is not identifying the anagrams.  Should be an easy fix.

Edit:  I just pasted in the first string sort routine a google search found for me and ran to get the following output:

```
./a.out trips
trips: 82 size: 5
strip

stirp

sprit

spirt
```

Answer (score 1):

Ther's no memory leak, but the code has some problems (the `replace_str` function need to be replaced by a correct version). The output of valgrind on my linux box:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./MEMORY_LEAK absurde
==13476== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13476== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13476== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13476== Command: ./MEMORY_LEAK absurde
==13476== 
==13476== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13476==    at 0x8048A9A: hash_lookup (MEMORY_LEAK.c:132)
==13476==    by 0x80489BD: add_to_hash_array (MEMORY_LEAK.c:113)
==13476==    by 0x804871C: main (MEMORY_LEAK.c:50)
==13476== 
absurde: 70 size: 7
==13476== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13476==    at 0x8048D1C: generate_anagrams (MEMORY_LEAK.c:169)
==13476==    by 0x8048795: main (MEMORY_LEAK.c:56)
==13476== 
==13476== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13476==    at 0x8048890: hash_dealloc (MEMORY_LEAK.c:81)
==13476==    by 0x80487D8: main (MEMORY_LEAK.c:64)
==13476== 
==13476== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13476==    at 0x4027BC2: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==13476==    by 0x804889C: hash_dealloc (MEMORY_LEAK.c:87)
==13476==    by 0x80487D8: main (MEMORY_LEAK.c:64)
==13476== 
==13476== 
==13476== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13476==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13476==   total heap usage: 360 allocs, 360 frees, 133,424 bytes allocated
==13476== 
==13476== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13476== 
==13476== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13476== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13476== ERROR SUMMARY: 65330 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```